# Distribution of this random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

What family of distributions does the following cdf belong to?  I know this is a dumb question but I've searched for quite a while online coming up empty.

$F(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      e^{-x^{-\alpha}} & x > 0  \\
      0 & x \leq 0 
   \end{cases}
$

for $\alpha > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Fréchet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) and is related to the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) and the [Gumbell distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) through the [Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem). All are encountered in the context of [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory).